# How to write REST service to integrate with Google Forms?

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

I have Created a Google form with fields Title, FirstName, LastName, Email, Company. When I click on submit button, All the data has to save into a custom object in my sandbox. For this I need to write REST service to integrate with salesforce. I am new to REST services.Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's some documentation that may help you out:

- [Send an email when a form is submitted](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/91588?hl=en).  You can combine this with Apex Email Services to save to your custom object.  This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it may be the best way to go as I believe it would be the easiest.
- [Use Google Apps Script on Form Submit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events?csw=1).  Combine this with the 3rd bullet point to send a rest call to Salesforce.
- [execute a rest api from google apps script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external?hl=en)
- [Create an SFDC record via rest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_create.htm)
- [General information on using SFDC's rest api](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your response Willard.I want to use "General information on using SFDC's rest api" which is your last bullet point.How to fire apex rest service when form submitted?

Comment: @manoj It's apparently all in the documentation. Have you tried looking at the docs?

Comment: But in API documentation of Google is in Google App Script. But I need to write code in Apex in a Rest service.Here App script won't be allowed.

Comment: You need app script to post a message to the SFDC rest api.  From your question, it looks like a record needs to be created in SFDC using REST.  There should be no apex involved here according to your question.  If so, please re-word so we understand the exact use case.